# How can my Knockout/RequireJS widget bind to the correct context when used in a site that also uses Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

## Scenario

I'm building a widget using RequireJS and KnockoutJS.  The widget calls `ko.applyBindings(widgetViewModel, thisWidget)` when it's instantiated.  The widget should be able to used in a site regardless if the site uses Knockout itself.

## Problem

When I drop my widget into a site that uses Knockout then the wrong view model is applied to the widget if the site invokes `ko.applyBindings(siteViewModel)` after the widget is setup.  The widget gets `siteViewModel` instead of the desired `widgetViewModel`.

## What I've tried so far

1. **Reordering the call to `ko.applyBindings(siteViewModel)` to happen before widget setup.**  This works but is not ideal because it places restrictions on how my widget is invoked.
2. **Add a custom binding for my widget that applies the correct binding context (i.e. `widgetViewModel` to my widget and returns `{controlsDescendantBindings: true};`**  Unfortunately the Knockout instance used by the site is not the same as the one used by my widget (because of Require) so I'd need to access the site's instance, possibly by looking the global namespace.

Comment: This is a challenging one. My thought at the moment would be to wrap your widget in a container that has a binding like I described [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html). Then, when your widget script loads, add the custom binding to your instance of KO and see if window.ko exists and add it there as well. The only remaining issue would be if you are using multiple KO versions through require.js or if there is a timing issue from when `ko.applyBindings` is called and when your module is loaded.  Would be good if we added a `stopBindings` like binding to KO core.

Comment: Yeah, that was the approach I was taking but I'm not 100% happy about having to divine the location of the outer container's instance of KO.

Comment: Right, currently I can't think of a better solution that doesn't also have drawbacks.  For example, you could use a [custom binding provider](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-2-custom-binding.html) that doesn't use `data-bind` and uses `spig-bind` (or whatever), but that might mess up the existing instance of KO. It could support both attributes, so that in the case that your page and your widget use the same instance of KO, you will still be okay. Still not great, just another thought.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were close with your second solution. What you can do is have a custom binding that just stops the site's bindings like the example provided on this page http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html

But as you say, if they are using knockout on the site already, you need this binding to be on that version of knockout, so you should wrap it in an if(ko) like this...

```
if(ko){
    ko.bindingHandlers.allowBindings = {
        init: function(elem, valueAccessor) {
            // Let bindings proceed as normal *only if* my value is false
            var shouldAllowBindings = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            return { controlsDescendantBindings: !shouldAllowBindings };
        }
    };
}
```

Then because you are using requirejs, you can map your version of knockout to something other than ko, like ko2 or whatever.

```
define(["knockout", "jquery"], function (ko2, $) {

    var myViewModel = {
        SomeComponentLevelBinding: ko2.observable()
    };

    ko2.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId'));
}
```

Then your html may look something like this...

```
<body>
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: SomeSiteLevelBinding"></span>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="allowBindings: false">
        <div id="someElementId">
            <span data-bind="text:SomeComponentLevelBinding"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Because the site already uses knockout and we added the allowBindings binding to that instance, we stop the site's version of knockout from controlling anything inside that div. Then because we do apply bindings just to the div inside it from our component using the component's version of knockout, we should have 2 versions of knockout on the same page playing nice together.

This should also be fine if they dont have knockout on the page, because if they dont, we dont add the allowBindings binding, and because we only apply bindings to the div inside it, the data-bind attribute with `allowBindings:false` is ignored in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing your widget in a way that it exports a applicator method, or may be included as a ViewModel property.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vXrh9/)

```
exports.widget = function(title){
    var self = this;

    self.title = ko.observable(title);

    self.apply = function(element){
        ko.applyBindings(self, element);
    };

    return self;
};
```

The HTML for your widget looks like this:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: title">Default</h1>
```

Now, we need to give both users a way to include it in their document that doesn't interfere with their workflow.

Non-KO users can simply bind it to the container of the `h1` element (let's pretend your module is called MyWidgets).

```
MyWidgets.widget("Not In KO").apply(document.getElementById('parentOfWidget'));
```

Knockout users can include it in their ViewModel, and use the `with` binding to give it context.

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.widgetInstance = new MyWidgets.widget("In KO");
    self.thing = "Other Thing";
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel);
```

Their HTML will look like this:

```
<div id="ko" data-bind="with: widgetInstance">
     <h1 data-bind="text: title">Default</h1>
</div>
<h2 data-bind="text: thing"></h2>
```

Notice that they can still create other properties, that don't conflict with any properties on your widget.

<sub>(p.s.  someone, please think of a better name than `apply` and edit my post)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a custom binding for your widget, like so:

```
define(["knockout", "jquery"], function (ko, $) {
    var widgetViewModel = {
        title: "My Widget Titel"
    };
    var widgetWrapperHtml = "<div data-bind=\"mywidget: true\"></div>";
    var widgetHtml = $("<div data-bind=\"text: $data.title\"</div>");

    ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.mywidget = true;
    ko.bindingHandlers.mywidget = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            // Create the widget context:
            var widgetBindingContext = widgetViewModel;
            // Or uncomment this line to created a child context:
            // var widgetBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(widgetBindingContext);

            ko.virtualElements.emptyNode(element);
            ko.virtualElements.prepend(element, widgetHtml[0]); 

            ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerContext, element);
        }
    };

    var applyWidgetToElement = function (element) {
        $(element).html(widgetWrapperHtml);
        ko.applyBindings({}, element);
    };

    return applyWidgetToElement;
})
```

Then you could use your widget like this:

```
require(["mywidget", "jquery"], function (widget, $) {
    widget($('.widgetStyle')[0]);
});
```

but also like this:

```
require(["mywidget", "jquery", "knockout"], function (widget, $, ko) {
    var viewModel = { title: "My App" };
    widget($('.widgetStyle')[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```